# PHP code to show a hidden button

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page with two buttons

```
<input type="submit" value="Start Analysis" name="StartAnalysis">  
<input type="submit" value="Download Results" name="DownloadResults">
```

When the page loads, I hide the "DownloadResults" button by default using jQuery's hide method.

After the user selects some input fields and submits the form using "StartAnalysis" I do some computation inside my PHP code. At the end of the computation I need to show user the "DownloadResults" button. How can I show it using PHP?

Thanks in advance!

Edited to include my HTML code (simplified)

```html
<?php
// START ANALYSIS START
if ( isset( $_POST['StartAnalysis'] ) ) {
    // Do processing here

    // Need help with this: I want Download Results Button to APPEAR so user can click it


}
// START ANALYSIS END
?>

<html>
    <script>
        // DownloadResults button is hidden by default
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('[name="DownloadResults"]').hide();
        });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">  
          <!-- Lots of INPUT FIELDS HERE -->

          <input type="submit" value="Start Analysis" name="StartAnalysis">  
          <input type="submit" value="Download Results" name="DownloadResults">  
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please show what you've got so far. No code, no answer.

Comment: how could we know? you havent shown your code

Comment: i think you should use jquery instead of php to unhide that button and use css to hide the button instead of jquery

Comment: Could you explain the overall flow of your application?  I have the feeling that you have one or two conceptual errors going on.

Comment: You can't use PHP without refreshing the page.

Comment: I have a ASP.NET background and in ASP.NET on the server side you have access (or a handle) to HTML elements so you can manipulate them.

Comment: but then the button will be hide again by your jquery on client-side. are u using php or ASP.NET?

Comment: Why don't you join me in my project's [chat room](https://gitter.im/userfrosting/UserFrosting).  I can try to help you clarify your overall design.

Comment: I just added my code. I am using PHP and jQuery. It's an HTML page with two buttons. Second button is hidden by default using jQuery. When the first button is pressed I do some processing using PHP. I need the second button to appear after that processing is completed. I mentioned ASP.NET because I'm using to being able to manipulate HTML elements from ASP.NET server side code and I don't know how to do it using PHP because I'm a beginner in PHP.

Comment: Right, that's why I'm asking you to join my chat so we can move the conversation off of SO (which discourages conversation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand correctly u want the button to be shown after form submit and you want to do it with PHP.maybe you can do it this way

first u must add a css for hidden and show.

```
.hidden{
    visibility="hidden";
}
.show{
    visibility="visible";
}
```

then in your php script u do it this way

```
if (isset($_POST['StartAnalysis'])) {
    # code...
    $class = 'show';
} else {
    $class = 'hidden';
}

<input type="submit" value="Start Analysis" name="StartAnalysis">  
<input type="submit" class="<?php echo $class; ?>" value="Download Results" name="DownloadResults">
```

this way you can hide and unhide with PHP. the button will be show on $_POST['StartAnalysis']

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a variable to true after the computation has been completed and once this variable is true, show your download button.

```
<?php 
    //assume you want to initially hide the button, you will set a flag to false
    $computationComplete = false;
    //function for all of your computation
    function analysisOfData(){
        //computation ex. 1+1=2
        $computationComplete = true;
    }
    //call your function/code to do your computation
    analysisOfData();
    //once you call your function to complete your computation perform the check    
   if($computationComplete){
       echo '<input type="submit" value="Download Results" name="DownloadResults">'; 
   }
```

Again, this is all assuming that once you submit the form you will remain on the same page. Which is what I'm assuming you want?